# How can I delete an element (game) from a list and find the second most repeated using Python?

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop, printing

```
import juegos_de_mesa


personas=input()
jd=input()

amigos=personas.split(";")
juegos_disponibles=jd.split(";")

print("Personas invitadas:", amigos)
print("Juegos disponibles:", juegos_disponibles)

jf=[]
for persona in amigos:
    juego_favorito = juegos_de_mesa.encontrar_juego_favorito(persona)
    jf.append(juego_favorito)

    
print("Juegos favoritos de los invitados:", jf)

def encontrar_elemento_mas_repetido(l):
    elemento_mas_comun = max(l, key=l.count)
    return elemento_mas_comun


juego_elegido= encontrar_elemento_mas_repetido(jf)
print("Eligiendo juego de mesa para jugar:")

def eliminar_elementos(lista, elemento):
    if elemento in lista:
        print("Decidimos jugar", juego_elegido,"! Que emocion!")
    else:
        print("Ibamos a jugar", juego_elegido,"pero no estaba disponible")
        jf.remove(juego_elegido)
        juego_elegido=encontrar_elemento_mas_repetido(lista)
        print("Decidimos jugar", "poto ","! Que emocion!")
    return juego_elegido
```

What the code asks is that based on a number of games that they give you as input, you can see which is the one that is repeated the most and then verify if it is among the available games, if it is not, delete it (with all its repetitions) and if it is, leave it there.

My problem is in the part of deleting the game and looking for the one with the most repetitions again or the first one after the repetition that we deleted.

Comment: You may want to look into the `Counter` class from the `collections` module.  It has a `most_common()` method that should help you with this.